# Use lintr() in Sublime Text 3 via SublimeLinter on Knitr Chunks

Tags: r, sublimetext3, knitr, r-markdown, sublimelinter

I'm trying to get [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) to lint the R chunks in my `*.Rnw` and `*.Rmd` documents via [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) which has recently [added support for knitr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/issues/32).

Lintr linting of `*.R` works fine, but not of knitr chunks in `*.Rnw` or `.Rmd`.

Lacking feature or am I missing a setting?
Here are my SublimeLinter settings:

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
    "error_color": "D02000",
    "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
    "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
    "lint_mode": "background",
    "linters": {
        "annotations": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "errors": [
                "FIXME"
            ],
            "excludes": [],
            "warnings": [
                "TODO",
                "README"
            ]
        },
        "lintr": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "cache": "TRUE",
            "excludes": [],
            "linters": "default_linters"
        },
        "r": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "cache": "TRUE",
            "excludes": [],
            "linters": "default_linters"
        }
    },
    "mark_style": "outline",
    "no_column_highlights_line": false,
    "passive_warnings": true,
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "python_paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "rc_search_limit": 3,
    "shell_timeout": 10,
    "show_errors_on_save": false,
    "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
    "syntax_map": {
        "html (django)": "html",
        "html (rails)": "html",
        "html 5": "html",
        "knitr (Markdown)": "r",
        "php": "html",
        "python django": "python",
        "r extended": "r"
    },
    "warning_color": "DDB700",
    "wrap_find": true
}
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, how did you get `lintr` to work in `Sublime`? I'm having a hard time figuring it out.